# Google Fit api is note returning Exercise data

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to get workout and food data from google fit apis for android. Below is the request

```
    public void createFitnessOptions() {
    fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build();
}

public DataReadRequest getReadRequest(Long startTime, Long endTime) {
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build();
    return readRequest;
}
    public void getHistory(Long startTime, Long endTime, boolean isPermissionGranted) {
      if (isPermissionGranted) {
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(context, account)
                .readData(getReadRequest(startTime, endTime))
                .addOnSuccessListener(response -> {
                    List<DataSet> dataSets = response.getDataSets();
                    for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                        dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.d("GoogleFit", "OnFailure()", e);
                });
    }
}
    private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
    DateFormat dateFormat = getTimeInstance();

    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
        Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
        Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
        }
    }
}
```

I have added activity from the google fit app but I am not getting any data in dataPoints.

Answer (score 0):

In onSuccess you should read dataSets from buckets instead of direct dataSets in response as you have applied bucketing strategy by day.

```
if (response.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
     for (Bucket bucket : readResponse.getBuckets()) {
        List<DataSet> bucketDataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
...
```